# How to detect if an Input file contains certain fields

Tags: java

I have this code here that needs to detect if any line in my input file doesn't contain a first name, last name, or grade. It then needs to throw a meaningful exception for the line that is not correct. I'm having trouble setting up my `if` statement to detect what's in each line. I know that `inputFile.next` only reads one word at a time and i'm pretty sure I need to create another variable for the whole line and incorporate `inputFile.nextLine`. If I take a name or grade out of my input file it throws an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception because it wants to see three words. I guess what I'm really trying to ask is how do I check to see if any line contains three words. Here's a sample of my code...

(The portion of the code that is commented out is another part of the assignment that needs to check if any grade is outside 0 to 100 and throw an exception if it is, that part I got to run fine.)

My Input File:

Mike Tony 98.7

Mary Tom 65.8

Ann Thomas 95.1

Alex Rider 178.6

```
package classwork11_2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Classwork11_2 {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{


    File input = new File("students.txt");

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(input);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("average.txt");

    ArrayList<Student> array = new ArrayList<>();

    double average = 0;
    String name = "";
    String header = "Average:";
    double sum = 0;

    while(inputFile.hasNext()){

        String firstLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        String[] word = firstLine.split(" ");

        String fName = inputFile.next();
        String lName = inputFile.next();
        String grades = inputFile.next();

        try{
         /*double g = Double.parseDouble(grades);
         if(g < 0 || g > 100)
            throw new MyException(g);*/

          if(word[0] == null || word[1] == null || word[2] == null)
              throw new MyException("The names don't exist");
      }
        catch(MyException e){

          System.out.println("Parsing line with " + fName + " " + lName + " 
" + grades + " gave the following error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

        Student student = new Student(fName, lName, grades);
        array.add(student);
        name += student.getfName() + " " + student.getlName() + ", ";

    }
    for(Student i : array){

        double num = Double.parseDouble(i.getGrade());
        sum += num;
        average = sum / array.size();
    }

    System.out.println(name.substring(0, name.length()-2));
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10.1f\n", header, average);
    inputFile.close();
    output.close();

}
}
```

My Exception Class:

```
    package chapter11_homework;


public class InvalidStringException extends Exception{


    public InvalidStringException(String msg){

        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Amount paid should be: $%.2f\n",calcWage(sum, hourRate)));`

Comment: Thank you!! I'm new at Java and methods, this worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You called the `calcWage` method, but didn't do anything with the value it returns. You can either store that value in a variable and then print the variable:

```
double wage = calcWage(sum, hourRate);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Amount paid should be: $%.2f\n",wage));
```

Or you could directly print the value returned by the method:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Amount paid should be: $%.2f\n",calcWage(sum, hourRate)));
```